# How do I get some(5) list of files in a directory and subfolders in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, file-extension

How do I get some list of files in a directory and sub_folders in Python?
I want to get only 5 .txt files in each directory.

I've been searched a lot, but can not find answer.

Need your help.

I've been testing Path, glob, os.walk().

```
import os
    for files in Path(".").glob(extension):
        print(files)
```

print all the list of file with extension

```
import os
    cpt = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(".")])
    cpt = [len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(dpath)]
    print(cpt)

[5, 25, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 4, 16, 4, 8]
```

Now all files, But 5 files in each directory.

Comment: Explain a bit more because I didn't quite understand.

Comment: Slice files up to five, what error you're facing?

Comment: Isn't this that you want?

Comment: Ohh there is the txt requirement I forgot sorry

Answer (score 0):

Get `recursively` first `5 x .txt files` starting from `dir_path`

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
    count = 0
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
            count += 1
            if count == 5:
                break
```